# Chrome Not Set Session's Cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, cookies

I have an ASP.NET MVC e-commerce application. Our help desk report me some chrome browsers have problems with our site. I found the problem but i cannot solve the problem. The problem is some chrome browsers not set session cookie. There is no cookie for session and the application use session of course so the application doesn't properly on some chrome browser. You can see my session setting at below.
What can i do? I don't solve the problem.

```
//global.asax
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["init"] = 0;
    Session.Timeout = 10080;
}

//web.config 
<sessionState cookieName="MySessionId" cookieSameSite="None" timeout="1000" mode="Custom" 
   customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
  <providers>
    <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" 
          host="x.x.x.x" accessKey="" ssl="false" port="6379" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

[image: There is no session cookie]

Comment: Just an idea but did you try to update nuget package for Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider ?

Comment: The problem was https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032. I added requireSSL property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution. Some chrome version was block same-site cookie without https.
I added to web.config "requireSsl" property.

Reason:https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032

Solution:

```
<httpCookies sameSite="None" requireSSL="true"  />
```